# How to programmatically create editable page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

I created pages programmatically. So now I want to edit them programmatically. When I editing my page I'm getting this exception.

```
 Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. \“File\r\n\”
```

So how I can create editable pages programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is,

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
    rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList wiki = rootWeb.Lists["Pages"];
    String url = wiki.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
    PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite(rootWeb.Site);
    string pageLayoutName = "EnterpriseWiki.aspx"; //Page Layout Name
    string layoutURL = rootWeb.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + pageLayoutName;
    PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
    PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(rootWeb);
    PublishingPage newWikiPage;
    string myWikiPage = "MyWikiPage.aspx"; //Page name
    newWikiPage = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(myWikiPage, layout);
    newWikiPage.Title = "My Wiki Page";
    newWikiPage.Update();
    rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```